# Regular expression between xml elements excluding a full element between similar elements

Tags: regex, xml, regex-negation, regex-group

I have the next elements:

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Common.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\LIB.XPTO.1.18.524.20\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Common.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\LIB.XPTO.1.0.1.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I want get all reference elements that contains the element `HintPath` or any other element, that is, I wan't that the `<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />` don't be geted by my regex.

I'm using the partern `/<Reference[\s\S]*?<\/Reference>` but this can't exclude the `<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />`.

How to do that?

### Edit

How result I want this on each match:

#### 1:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Common.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <HintPath>..\..\packages\LIB.XPTO.1.18.524.20\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Sockets.Common.Http.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
```

#### 2:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
          <HintPath>..\..\packages\LIB.XPTO.1.18.524.20\lib\net45\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2988730

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zTKSE6/1).

```
<\/?Reference.*\/?>
```

Comment: See edit please.

Comment: You should look into using a parser.

Comment: how can I do that?